# Why the JButton.getModel().isPressed() always return false

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have two questions, the first question is JButton.getModel().isPressed always return false.

```
public void setReadButtonStatus() {
        if(readButton.getModel().isPressed()==true) {
            readButton.getModel().setPressed(false);
        }
        else {
            readButton.getModel().setPressed(true);
        }
        System.out.println(readButton.getModel().isPressed());
    }
```

When I call the setReadButtonStatus function, the isPressed always false.

the other question is How can I do let two JButton Simultaneously have pressed status

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear, but my guess is that you're looking for toggle buttons. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JToggleButton.html

Answer (score 0):

Your first answer: `isPressed()` determine the button is pressed by mouse or not. you can see the result of `isPressed()` in below program :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

class EventExample implements ActionListener {
  JFrame frame;
  JTextArea area;
  JScrollPane pane;
  JButton button1;
  JButton button2;
  JPanel contentPane;
  JPanel buttonPanel;
  boolean flag = true;

  public EventExample() {
    frame = new JFrame();

    area = new JTextArea(10,10);
    area.setEditable(true);
    area.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("EVENT"));

    button1 = new JButton("Button1");
    button1.addActionListener(this);


    button2 = new JButton("Button2");
    button2.addActionListener(this);

    contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.add(button1);
    buttonPanel.add(button2);

    contentPane.add(area);
    contentPane.add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
    MouseAdapter adapter = new MouseAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        area.setText(area.getText()+"\nMouse Pressed Event Occur Button isPressed  = "+button1.getModel().isPressed());
      }
      public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        area.setText(area.getText()+"\nMouse Moved Event Occur Button isPressed  = "+button1.getModel().isPressed());
      }
    };

    button1.addMouseListener(adapter);
    frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == button2) {
      if(flag == true) {
        flag = false;
        button1.getModel().setPressed(false);
        area.setText(area.getText()+"\nMouse Pressed Event Occur in Button2 Button 1 isPressed  value = "+button1.getModel().isPressed());

      } else {
        flag = true;
        button1.getModel().setPressed(true);
        area.setText(area.getText()+"\nMouse Pressed Event Occur in Button2 Button 1 isPressed  value = "+button1.getModel().isPressed());

      }
    }
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new EventExample();
  }
}
```

If you run this program you understand that when the `isPressed()` return `true`.After running a program you can see `isPressed()` method return `true` when pressed action occur, if move action ocuur on button it return `false`